# MYSQL: copy/clone column values to another

Tags: mysql

I can't figure it out how to clone all row values to another row
(Table 'users' with ~4k entries)

```
|id| login| password| email|

| 1|login1|password1|email1|

| 2|login2|password2|email2|

| 3|login3|password3|email3|
```

I would like to clone all 'email' row values to 'login' row for all users(id)
Values in row 'login' should be the same as in 'email'

```
|id| login| password| email|

| 1|email1|password1|email1|

| 2|email2|password2|email2|

| 3|email3|password3|email3|
```

How to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple update query required:

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET login = email;
```

Comment: Yes it is. By the way, please practice marking answer as accepted if it works for you so that others find it useful. [**How to accept answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: thank you for explanation. I´m new here and did not know about it, but already has been done :)

Comment: No problem mate. It's a good practice. By the way, welcome to `SO` :)